# Sql Fiddle errors

Tags: sql

I am trying to create SQL statements for an assignment in SQL Fiddle and I keep getting the error "Cannot add foreign key constraint". I have tried various things but I recieve different errors when I change things. What am I doing wrong?

```
  CREATE TABLE Person (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    FName varchar(255),
    LName varchar(255),
    Preferred_Name varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    )
    ;
    
     CREATE TABLE Song (
      ID varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      Title varchar(255),
      Run_Time varchar(255),
      Lyrics varchar(255),
      LeadID int,
      FOREIGN KEY (LeadID) REFERENCES Person(ID),
      PRIMARY KEY (ID)
      )
      ;
      
      CREATE TABLE Album (
        Title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        Run_Time int,
        Release_Year TIMESTAMP,
        PRIMARY KEY (Title)
        )
        ;
        
        CREATE TABLE Has (
          Album_Title varchar(255),
          Song_Title varchar(255),
          FOREIGN KEY (Album_Title) REFERENCES Album(Title),
          FOREIGN KEY (Song_Title) REFERENCES Song(ID)
          )
          ;
          
          CREATE TABLE Part_Of (
            PersonID int,
            SongID int,
            Role varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Person(ID),
            FOREIGN KEY (SongID) REFERENCES Song(ID),
            PRIMARY KEY (Role)
            )
            ;
```

Comment: Perhaps you should use a different fiddle site (SQLFiddle doesn't work very well these days), and one that offers some other DB. For example, this error message from SQLServer makes it pretty clear what the DB doesn't like: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1d9506685b75a114139886d5ebe9436d

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine by the power vested in you, you can just edit it..

Comment: Also I would advocate not naming your tables some bland thing like Has, PartOf

Answer (score 0):

In the Song and Has tables you defined Song.ID and Has.Song_Title as a varchar(255). In the Part_Of  table you defined SongID as an int. This is why the foreign key is failing. Use the same datatype in all tables (INT seems like a good option) to fix this.

```
CREATE TABLE Song (
      ID varchar(255) NOT NULL, <------
      Title varchar(255),
      Run_Time varchar(255),
      Lyrics varchar(255),
      LeadID int,
      FOREIGN KEY (LeadID) REFERENCES Person(ID),
      PRIMARY KEY (ID)
      )
      ;

CREATE TABLE Has (
      Album_Title varchar(255),
      Song_Title varchar(255), <-----
      FOREIGN KEY (Album_Title) REFERENCES Album(Title),
      FOREIGN KEY (Song_Title) REFERENCES Song(ID)
  )
  ;


CREATE TABLE Part_Of (
      PersonID int,
      SongID int, <-----
      Role varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Person(ID),
      FOREIGN KEY (SongID) REFERENCES Song(ID),
      PRIMARY KEY (Role)
      )
      ;
```

Comment: I went ahead and changed both to int and I am still recieving the same error.

Comment: Your Has table also references Song.ID, i'll add it to the answer